# LIFERAY --- Why Can't I Add Configuration Option To My Portlet?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I have an admin-only portlet (you can't add it to a site). I can add the edit portlet mode with no problem and it appears under the gearbox Options menu as Preferences. However, I cannot add the Configure option, even though I do it exactly as shown in [Liferay 6.2 User Guide](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-configurable-portlet-preferences). It does not appear under the gearbox Options menu as it should (as 'Configuration').

I did:

- correctly add the default configuration action class in
  liferay-portlet.xml
- specify .jsp file in portlet.xml
- add config portlet mode in portlet.xml
- add config-template init param

In both liferay-portlet.xml and portlet.xml I also specify another `<portlet>`, which can be added on a site (and does not appear under admin content) for which Configuration appears with no problem. Even if I copy its configuration options to the first  (the admin one), configuration option for it still doesn't appear.

So what should I do to make Configuration option for my portlet to appear?

[image: Liferay Portlet Gearbox Options Menu]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: Isn't building a community's knowledge database the most important?

Comment: You did read the answers and implications, right? It's about duplicate work, respecting those that help you for free, the common case that getting an answer in one place is unknown in the other etc. Just link all posts (in all directions) and people can check if investing time for an answer is necessary at all. When an answer is just posted to one place, you'll end up with two half community knowledge databases.